# EF6/LINQ MySQL - Won't Insert

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6

Using EF6/LINQ with a MySQL server. I have a DataGridView binded to a BindingList of Entities using a DataTable. Everything works fine, even deleting records. But I can't insert records that have not already been in the database.

What I mean by this is that if I select a record from the database, then delete it, SaveChanges(), and then reinsert it, it reinserts itself! But if I try to insert ex. new tcompanyaddress(), set its properties, and insert it? Doesn't work.

The ultimate goal is to emulate a transaction clearing all addresses associated with a CompanyID FK in the DB, then simply reinserting the most current edited addresses from the BindingList. Again, it works... but not on new entries.

```
using (JobTrackerEntities context = new JobTrackerEntities())
{
    context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString += ";password=orbitman1;";
    // Update main profile
    tcompany companyRow = context.tcompany.Find(Company.CompanyID);
    companyRow.CompanyName = Company.CompanyName;
    // Update foreign profiles
    var addresses = from address in context.tcompanyaddress // Retreive all addresses that were removed
                    where address.CompanyID == Company.CompanyID
                    select address;
    // Clear existing addresses
    foreach (tcompanyaddress address in addresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Remove " + address.LocationName);
        context.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    addresses = from address in context.tcompanyaddress // Retreive all addresses that were removed
                where address.CompanyID == Company.CompanyID
                select address;
    Console.WriteLine("After clear: " + addresses.Count());
    // Replace with new addresses
    foreach (tcompanyaddress address in CompanyAddresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add " + address.LocationName);
        context.tcompanyaddress.Add(address);
    }
    // Commit transaction
    context.SaveChanges();
    addresses = from address in context.tcompanyaddress // Retreive all addresses that were removed
                where address.CompanyID == Company.CompanyID
                select address;
    Console.WriteLine("After add: " + addresses.Count());

    RefreshProfileForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple. Turns out I wasn't setting the CompanyID FK when I added a new address to the BindingList, which meant the query never selects it.